# System.Data.SqlClient is not in my assembly references

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. Simply put, `System.Data.SqlClient` isn't in my assembly references. Can anyone help me out with this one? I can't find anywhere to like, download the file online.

Comment: If you're writing in .NET Core, you have add it as a Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient

Answer (score 5):

In the solution window

1- Right click on your project

2- select Manage Nuget packages

3- select the Browse tab

4- type 'System.Data.SqlClient' in the search box

5- you will see the package and install it, you just need to select the founded package and press Install button on the right side.